# How to search paginated results from the Twitch API

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitch

I'm trying to search for games by name from the twitch API, I'm able to do so using the following code:

```
var games = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top',
    headers: {
        'Client-ID':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      games.push(data.data)
    }
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  var search = "Counter-Strike".toLowerCase();
  var results = games[0].filter(function(data) {
    return data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1;
  });
  console.log(results);
});
```

The problem is that this only returns 20 results, how can I search through all the results?

The [twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-top-games) does provide a patination in the response but I don't know how it would be used to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've added in your question to the Twitch API shows how to query for more results and how to page them.

`?first=20&after=20`

The following code should return the second page of 20 results, so from 21 to 40.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top?first=20&after=20',
    headers: {
        'Client-ID':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      games.push(data.data)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to search through all the games, e.g all games that have the word "counter" or "fort"

Comment: What about using this call [Get Games](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-games)? This could cover your needs.